# How can I avoid referencing an Excel sheet each time I need a piece of data?

Tags: c#, selenium

I've been working towards building a Selenium framework to test the web app I work on. I've recently been experimenting with data-driven testing using an external Excel sheet to store CSS element names, as well as data for submission forms and such. I've included my code below, as you can see I'm "calling" Excel for every bit of data I need. This is taking forever. Is there a way to import the data all at once and do it "in memory"?

```
public string getCell(string sheet, string a)
    {
        string workbookPath = @"C:\exceltest.xlsx";

        Excel.Application excelApp;
        Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook;
        Excel.Sheets excelSheets;

        excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(workbookPath);
        excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Sheets;
        excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(sheet);

        Excel.Range range = excelWorksheet.get_Range(a, a);
        string cell = range.Value.ToString();

        return cell;
    }

    [Test]
    public void addGuest()
    {
        newSession();

        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(getCell(css, "B11"))).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(getCell(css, "B12"))).Click();
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());

        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(getCell(css, "B13"))).SendKeys(getCell(property, "B3"));
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(getCell(css, "B14"))).SendKeys(getCell(property, "B4"));
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(getCell(css, "B15"))).SendKeys(getCell(property, "B5"));
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(getCell(css, "B16"))).SendKeys(getCell(property, "B6"));
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(getCell(css, "B17"))).SendKeys(getCell(property, "B7"));
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(getCell(css, "B18"))).SendKeys(getCell(property, "B8"));
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(getCell(css, "B19"))).SendKeys(getCell(property, "B9"));
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(getCell(css, "B20"))).SendKeys(getCell(property, "B10"));
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(getCell(css, "B21"))).SendKeys(getCell(property, "B11"));
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(getCell(css, "B22"))).SendKeys(getCell(property, "B12"));
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(getCell(css, "B23"))).SendKeys(Keys.Down);
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(getCell(css, "B24"))).SendKeys(Keys.Down);
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(getCell(css, "B25"))).SendKeys(getCell(property, "B13"));
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(getCell(css, "B26"))).SendKeys(getCell(property, "B14"));
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(getCell(css, "B27"))).Click();

    }

    [Test]
    public void newSession()
    {
        string baseURL = "https://website.com";

        string property = "Property";

        //Login
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL);
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(getCell(css, "B1"))).SendKeys(getCell("Sheet1", "A1"));
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(getCell(css, "B2"))).SendKeys(getCell("Sheet1", "B1"));
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(getCell(css, "B3"))).Click();

        //Property>New Session

        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(getCell(css, "B4"))).SendKeys(getCell(property, "B1"));
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(getCell(css, "B5"))).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(getCell(css, "B6"))).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(getCell(css, "B7"))).Click();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to use Excel like this. You are better off just putting the CSS Selectors in the code. Excel is better used for things like data validation. For example, I work on eComm sites (think amazon.com or any site where stuff is sold). I have product data in Excel sheets... things like product ids, names, quantities, pricing, and so on. I'm given a sheet in a certain format and I have a script that reads one line at a time and walks through the site and purchases that product while validating the different bits of data as it goes. Each week I get a new sheet or two or three... that's a better use of Excel, IMO.

I would do something like this...

```
public class Test
{
    private By sampleElementLocator = By.cssSelector("sampleId");

    public void addGuest()
    {
        driver.findElement(sampleElementLocator).click();
        ...
    }
}
```